# i want to translate this upcode in assembler programming keil uVision 5

Tags: c, assembly

(**a , b can be any number, between -20 and 20.. Find final values of
i, j, and k for three pairs of a and b having the relationships a > b, a < b, and a = b**)

```
i =1
j=0
k = -1
while (i > j) {
i = i + a – 2 * j;
if (j >= k) {
i = i + 2;
k = k – b + 2 * j;
}
j++;
```

Keil ( this my version but why it end up infinity loop )

```
   MOV r0, #1
   MOV r1, #0
   MOV r2,  #0
   SUB r2,r2,#1; k = -1
   MOV r4, #4 ;a =4
   MOV r5, #6
   MOV r8, #2
   B whileLoop

whileLoop
   CMP r0,r1
   BLE stop
   MUL r3,r1,r8 ; r3 = 2*j
   ADD r0, r0,r4
   SUB r0, r0, r  3;  i = i + a -2*j
   B ifloop

ifloop
   CMP r1,r2  ;j>=k?
   BLT A
   ADD r0,r0,#2  
   MUL r3,r1,r8 ;r3 = 2*j
   SUB r2,r2,r5  ;k = k -b
   ADD r2,r2,r3   ; k = k-b+2j
   B  A
A
   ADD r1,r1,#1  ;j++
   B whileLoop
stop B stop
   ENDP
   END
```

Comment: I just want to know if my code transfer from C code is right or not

Comment: Then compare your code with the output of some C compiler. Try also [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: lol if I know I would not asked it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: https://godbolt.org/ has online ARM-gcc and ARM-clang and nice formatting of the asm output, so it's a better place to point people who should ask a compiler.